# What is my clock telling me to do?

Tags: language

My two year old played with my calendar clock, and while it still shows the correct time, now it tells me my name, where I work, and also something I should do, which I'd rather not.  What is it?

Hint 1

> The clock is a fairly cheap device available globally - I own and use it in real life, it is operating as designed and not broken in any way

Hint 2

> What I should do, my place of work, and my name show up sequentially, not at the same time (and are not my real life info)

Hint 3

> What I should do, my place of work, and my name show up every week

Hint 4

> It's showing my name today, showed my place of work yesterday, and what I should do two days ago.  Bonus: it'll show my wife's name in two days.

Hint 5

> All of this repeats every week.

Hint 6

> The solution has only to do with the display that shows the current day of the week.  It is not related to segment displays.

Comment: I don't have a whole answer yet, but is your name rot13(Wnfba) by any chance?  I can see how the calendar feature might cause that to appear...

Comment: rot13(Vf lbhe svnaprr'f anzr Wnarg)?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman no - I'm preparing some hints for the question

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri no, although her name could also show up

Comment: I can't shake off the sensation that your name is *May* and it's something to do with April 30th and 1st of May. Am I way off?

Comment: @KonradViltersten My name rot13(qbrf unir guerr yrggref) but the solution has nothing to do with rot13(fcrpvsvp qngrf, nf Uvag 5 rkcynvaf)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Typo? Deep hidden message?

Comment: @KonradViltersten that is a coded message, you can decode it here https://rot13.com/ They usually use this to not spoil things for other people while reading the comments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If a 2 year old played with your clock, it could have

> changed the display language to German (see the [language](/questions/tagged/language) tag)

With your hints given

> - it shows up once in a week
>  - it shows up sequentially.
>  so I think we are searching weekday names that match "Name, Place of work, Do something"
>   German Weekdays:
>   Montag (Monday)
>   Dienstag (Tuesday)
>   Mittwoch (Wednesday)
>   Donnerstag (Thursday)
>   Freitag (Friday)
>   Samstag (Saturday)
>   Sonntag (Sunday)
>   Mostly abbreviated with the first three letters

Then let us pick a name

> **Don** from Donnerstag (Thursday)

Pick a place of work

> **MIT** from Mittwoch (Wednesday)

Pick something you don't wanna do

> **Die** from Dienstag (Tuesday)

And bonus, your wife's name

> **Sam** from Samstag (Saturday)

And why wasn't it there before?

> The English abbreviations would be different, so they started to show after your child changed the language of the clock

Comment: Translate the numbers into German and find the name of an athletic gear company

Comment: @user3294068 Found it, you mean rot13(Qervffvt Nguyrgvp). I dont think that numbers are written out on a calender clock.  So the number would be there before in english too.

Comment: @user3294068 rot13(Trezna qbrf cynl vagb gur fbyhgvba, ohg vg'f zhpu zber fgenvtugsbejneq)

Comment: This has to be it. Nice job!

Comment: That's ingenious. rot13(Ohg V nyjnlf pevatr jura V frr gur Trezna jrrxqnlf nooerivngrq gb guerr yrggref vafgrnq bs whfg gjb.)

Comment: This is what I had in mind, congrats!

Comment: So after showing the wife's name, it then tells us who was responsible for all this?

Answer (score 28):

I think that the calendar clock is now looking like this:

> [image]
>  Because your 2-year old put it upside down, when it was displaying 09:31:0X (the X is not important at all)
>  [image]

You name is

> DIEGO
> (upside down 09310 - 0 = "D", 1 = "I", 3 = "E", 9 = "G", 0 = "O")

You work at

> San Diego

It tells you to

> DIE - which you should do eventually, but you would rather not
>  GO - you should go somewhere, but you don't want to

Comment: Good guess, but the solution I'm looking for does involve the "calendar" component of the clock.  Upvote for getting very close to the right solution though!

Answer (score 23):

If the time and date are

> 7:11 on Wednesday, July 10

the clock would be showing

> your place of work, **7-Eleven** (7:11),
>  your name, **Julio** (Jul 10),
>  and something you'd rather not do: **Wed**.

Comment: Great one!  Didn't think there would be so many possible answers.  The one I was thinking of is still out there, also see the hints I added.

Comment: But what did the two year old do with the clock?

Answer (score 2):

Another (not so) creative answer:

> The lines on a clock change as follows:
>  - **Wednesday** ([that's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday_Addams) your name)
>  - **8.1 1:15** (on a 7-segment display it can be easily read as *BILLS* - you should pay bills, but definitely do not want to do this)
>  - **99°F** (reads as [GGF](https://www.ggf.org.uk/), your workplace) - this clock is equipped by a temperature sensor (this is not uncommon), and your 2-year-old heated the clock with her hands while playing (99°F, or 37.2°C, is close to body temperature)

Unfortunately

> today is really August 1, but not Wednesday.